# How to tell if a distro was made using Gentoo

Tags: linux, gentoo, linux-distributions

I've downloaded a Linux distribution and tried it on my PC. When I checked the documentation I noticed that there was no information about how it was developed. I wonder if it was developed using Gentoo so I did a 
`grep -ir 'Gentoo' /` and found these matches:

```
/lib64/modules/3.18.140/kernel/drivers/media/dvb/frontends/mt312.ko
/lib64/modules/3.18.140/kernel/drivers/mtd/maps/gpio-addr-flash.ko
/lib64/modules/3.18.140/kernel/drivers/staging-speakup/speakup.ko
/lib64/modules/3.18.140/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/ums/alauda.ko
/lib64/modules/3.18.140/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/ums-usbat.ko
/lib64/modules/3.18.140/kernel/drivers/video/uvesafb.ko
```

Do these matches mean that it was developed using Gentoo? How to tell exactly if a Linux distro was made using Gentoo?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “how it was developed”? What you found in those kernel modules are almost certainly e-mail addresses.

Comment: I mean how it was put together. Like the Google ChromeOS was put together using Gentoo.

Answer (score 3):

#### How do I find out my Linux distribution?

> > Finding your distribution release
>
> There may be times when you need to know the release number you
>   currently use. Again, there’s a handy command to find that
>   information. Do the following:
>
> 1. Open a terminal window
> 2. Issue the command
>
>    ```
>    lsb_release -a
>    ```
> 3. Take note of the information displayed
>
>    [image]

Source [How to Find Your Linux Version or Distro Release, and Why It Matters - Linux.com](https://www.linux.com/tutorials/how-find-your-linux-version-or-distro-release-and-why-it-matters/)

Alternatives:

> ```
> cat /etc/*release
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> cat /etc/issue*
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> cat /proc/version
> ```

Source [What's my OS? What is my OS?](https://whatsmyos.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to check the (presumably public) history of your distribution.

Why does it matter to you, anyway? "Distribution X is derived from Y" doesnt't say much, *all* pilfer freely from what others do, all start with more or less the same upstream code bases, there are areas where they actively cooperate.